# Handling ServiceStack exception on silverlight in the right way

Tags: silverlight, servicestack

I've some problem getting the exception on the silverlight side...

consider this simple example

Service :

```
public void Any(NoResultResponseRequest request)
{
   throw new Exception("Someone give me an hug");
}
```

Dto :

```
 public class NoResultResponseRequest:IReturnVoid
 {
    public int Id { get;set; }
 }
```

and on the silverlight part :

```
    private SS.JsonServiceClient  GetService()
    {

        Uri uri = new Uri(App.Current.Host.Source, "../api/");

        var timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 45, 0, 0);// TimeSpan.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("servicestackTimeout"));
        SS.JsonServiceClient client = new SS.JsonServiceClient(uri.AbsoluteUri) { Timeout = timeout };

        client.ShareCookiesWithBrowser = true;
        client.StoreCookies = true;
        client.EmulateHttpViaPost = true;

        return client;
    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var client = GetService();
        var request = new NoResultResponseRequest
        {
            Id = 9
        };

            client.PostAsync(request).ContinueWith(x =>
                {
                  //got a Not found error
                });
    }
```

If I watch at the traffic with fiddler I've the following JSon

```
{"responseStatus":{"errorCode":"Exception","message":"Someone give me an hug","stackTrace":"[NoResultResponseRequest: 15/09/2014 11:59:16]:\n[REQUEST: {id:9}]\nSystem.Exception: Someone give me an hug\r\n   at SilverlightException.Web.TestService.Any(NoResultResponseRequest request) in c:\\Projects\\2014\\SilverlightException\\SilverlightException.Web\\TestService.cs:line 14\r\n   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceExec`1.<>c__DisplayClass6.<CreateExecFn>b__5(Object service, Object request)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.Execute(IRequest request, Object instance, TRequest requestDto)","errors":[]}}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am having trouble reproducing the NotFound part of your error, would you be able to create a project to share with the error occurring? Might help if you could also capture the error in the ContinueWith as well to see the details of it. The one thing that looks odd to me is the construction of the host Uri with the relative '../api/', double check path given to the JsonServiceClient.

Comment: Hello Layoric, here's a DB link https://www.dropbox.com/s/hrtl0alsfjlscr5/SilverlightException.rar?dl=0 ... thanks in advance

Comment: In addition to Layoric's comments, in order to comment it would help to see the service that is hosting the Any(NoResultResponseRequest request).  Have you tried hitting it up in Chrome or seeing the metadata page?

Comment: As Marc's says in his answer, it seems Silverlight on web has a lot of problems/limitation when it comes to reading anything but 200 responses. So much so that even an MSDN article suggests changing error response codes to 200 (as Marc is suggesting). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844556(v=vs.95).aspx. This comes with it's own range of problems, but seems hard/impossible to avoid with specific SL client situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the EmulateHttpViaPost to false it should work as expected...

Actually if you switch to http emulation you have to handle the WebServiceException your self, that is, Silverlight could not read http response that is not http status 200.

So basically you need to add a server side filter that will change the http status code to 200

Server Side :

In your Configure method add :
    GlobalResponseFilters.Add(HttpOverrideFriendExceptionFilter);

```
private static void HttpOverrideFriendExceptionFilter(IRequest request, IResponse httpResponse, object response)
    {
        if (request.Headers[HttpHeaders.XHttpMethodOverride] == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Func<int, string, ResponseError> createRespErr = (statusCode, statusDesc) => new ResponseError
        {
            ErrorCode = statusCode.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            FieldName = "__HTTP_EXCEPTION",
            Message = statusDesc
        };

        var httpDomainError = response as HttpError;
        if (httpDomainError != null)
        {
            httpResponse.StatusCode = 200;
            httpDomainError.ResponseStatus.Errors = new List<ResponseError>();
            httpDomainError.ResponseStatus.Errors.Add(createRespErr(httpDomainError.Status, httpDomainError.ErrorCode));
            httpDomainError.ResponseStatus.Errors.Add(new ResponseError
            {
                ErrorCode = httpDomainError.ErrorCode, Message = httpDomainError.Message
            });
            httpDomainError.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            httpResponse.Dto = httpDomainError;
            return;
        }

        var httpResult = response as IHttpResult;
        if (httpResult != null)
        {
            if (httpResult.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var errorStatus = httpResult.Status;
                var statusDesc = httpResult.StatusDescription;
                var respStatus = httpResult.Response.GetResponseStatus() ?? new ResponseStatus
                {
                    Errors = new List<ResponseError>()
                };
                var errResp = httpResult.Response as ErrorResponse ?? new ErrorResponse
                {
                    ResponseStatus = respStatus
                };

                httpResult.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
                httpResult.Response = errResp;

                errResp.ResponseStatus.Errors.Add(createRespErr(errorStatus, statusDesc));
            }
            return;
        }

        var ex = response as Exception;
        if (ex != null)
        {
            var httpError = new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.OK, ex)
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Response = new ErrorResponse
                {
                    ResponseStatus = new ResponseStatus
                    {
                        Errors = new List<ResponseError>()
                    }
                }
            };
            httpError.ResponseStatus.Errors.Add(createRespErr(500, "Unhandle Exception"));
            httpResponse.Dto = httpError;
        }
    }
```

At the Client Level you need to wrap every call like this :

```
public class SilverlightClient : JsonServiceClient
{
    private const string InternalFieldError = "__HTTP_EXCEPTION";

    public SilverlightClient(string baseUri) 
        : base(baseUri)
    {

    }

    public TResponse SilverlightSend<TResponse>(object requestDto, string httpMethod)
    {
        var r = CustomMethod<HttpWebResponse>(httpMethod, requestDto);
        var text = r.ReadToEnd();

        AssertWebServiceException(text);

        return Deserialize<TResponse>(text);
    }

    public Task<TResponse> SilverlightSendAsync<TResponse>(object request, string httpMethod)
    {
        var task = CustomMethodAsync<HttpWebResponse>(httpMethod, request);
        var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<TResponse>();

        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            try
            {
                var text = t.Result.ReadToEnd();
                AssertWebServiceException(text);

                if (typeof(TResponse) == typeof(HttpWebResponse))
                {
                    tsc.SetResult((TResponse)(object)t.Result);
                    return;
                }

                tsc.SetResult(Deserialize<TResponse>(text));
            }
            catch (WebServiceException ex)
            {
                tsc.SetException(ex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tsc.SetException(ex);
            }
        });

        return tsc.Task;
    }

    private void AssertWebServiceException(string text)
    {
        if (text != null && text.IndexOf(InternalFieldError, StringComparison.Ordinal) > -1)
        {
            var errResponse = Deserialize<ErrorResponse>(text);
            ThrowWebServiceException(errResponse);
        }
    }

    private static void ThrowWebServiceException(IHasResponseStatus errorResponse)
    {
        var respStatus = errorResponse.ResponseStatus;
        var serviceEx = new WebServiceException
        {
            StatusCode = 500,
            StatusDescription = respStatus.Message,
            ResponseDto = errorResponse,
        };

        var httpCode = respStatus.Errors.FirstOrDefault(e => e.FieldName == InternalFieldError);
        if (httpCode != null)
        {
            serviceEx.StatusCode = Convert.ToInt32(httpCode.ErrorCode);
            serviceEx.StatusDescription = httpCode.Message;
        }

        throw serviceEx;
    }
}
```

I know that is kind of funky but you have no choice since Silverlight has many limitation like it cannot read custom http header and so on

Hope that helps

Regards

Comment: Excuse me, 2 things... how do I register that service with servicestack? second on the client side ... where should I place this? I don't see any async method or callback and SL only works async... Thanks

Comment: Its not service but a global response filter : https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters

Comment: Actually Silverlight is able to use the synchronous API when the code is not running on the UI thread, also for the silverlight side it will be easier if you derive your own class from the JsonServiceClient since you will have access to some protected method that will help deserializing without embedding your license number in your assembly...

Comment: Hello I had to serialize a byte[] as return (a pdf) but I got an exception "Input string was an incorrect format" ... I've seen that the contentype is application/octet-stream ... I think there's something wrong with the Deserialize<T>